# Function App custom dependencies, how to install and reference python packages locally?

Tags: python, azure-function-app

I am attempting to deploy a python Function App on Azure, however, due to the required configuration, all the outbound traffic must route internally. This means `pip` fails during the build as it cannot reach PyPI. Locally I use our own artifactory for python packages, but this requires some setup of proxies and certificates.

Instead, I saw you can do a custom build by `pip` installing local to the project

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#custom-dependencies

```
$ pip install --target"<project-dir>/.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r requirements.txt
```

Is this all I need to do? Or do I have to update my package imports to reference this folder, and if so how do I do that correctly?

```
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceClient
```

would it become?

```
.python_packages.lib.site-packages.azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceClient
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to import packages from a given folder (for example a folder named `packages`) you can do the following in your script.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("path_to_packages_folder")
```

All the packages that are in that folder will now be available for import, so you can now simply do the normal import: `from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceClient`.